# GraphQL Schema Testing: From Schema to Object Type

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, graphql, chai

I want to test my GraphQLSchema very basic if an specific Field is on my ObjectType.

The following TypeDefs I have.

```
export const categoryTypeDefs = `
  type Category {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
  } ... `
```

The test looks like this currently.

```
describe('Category Schema', () => {
        const categorySchema = graphql.buildSchema(categoryTypeDefs)
        it('Should have an Category field of type String', () => {
            expect(categorySchema.getTypeMap).to.have.property("name");
        })
    })
```

Now my question is if there is any possibility to get from my Schema the ObjectType of Category and access the method ".getFields()". In the end I want following Tests.

```
expect(categoryType.getFields()).to.have.property('name');
expect(categoryType.getFields().name.type).to.deep.equals(graphql.GraphQLString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution was then easier then I expected. We just have to cast the return from getType to the GraphQLObjectType in TypeScript.

So whenever someone has the same issue.

```
describe('Category Schema', () => {
    it('Should have an Name field of type String', () => {
        let testType = schema.getType('Category') as GraphQLObjectType;

        expect(testType.getFields()).to.have.property("name");
        expect(testType.getFields().name.type).to.deep.equals(GraphQLString)
    })
})
```